# How to define a function of callbacks where callback N's argument is the merge of the N-1 callback return types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Below, `specialFunction` takes N callbacks and constrains them such that each callback's only argument is the merge of the N-1 callback return types. My goal is to avoid hardcoding the number of arguments that `specialFunction` takes.

```js
const specialFunction = <something>
specialFunction(
  () => ({a: 1}), 
  (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.a)
    return { b: 2}
  }),
  (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.a)
    console.log(arg.b)
  }
) // does not error
specialFunction(
  () => ({a: 1}), 
  (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.b)
    return { b: 2}
  }),
  (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.a)
    console.log(arg.c) // typescript error here
  }
)
```

But I am not sure how to proceed to make this possible.

I've tried this so far, but it doesn't work

```js
type MergeArr<Arr extends unknown[], Merged = void> =
  Arr['length'] extends 0 ?
  Merged :
  Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? 
  MergeArr<Tail,
    {[key in keyof Merged | keyof Head] : 
        key extends keyof Head ? 
        Head[key] : 
        key extends keyof Merged ? Merged[key] : never
    }> : 
  never

type Take<Arr extends readonly unknown[], N extends `${number}` | number, Until extends unknown[] = []> = 
  `${Until['length']}` extends N ? 
  Until : 
  Until['length'] extends N ? 
  Until : 
  Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? 
  Take<Tail, N, [...Until, Head]> :
  never
const specialFunction = <T extends unknown[]>
(
  ...args: 
  {
    [K in keyof T] : (
      params: MergeArr<Take<T, K>>
    ) => T[K]
  }
) => true
specialFunction(() => ({a:2}), ({a}) => ({b: 2}), ({b}) => ({c: 3})) // errors at third argument
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As far as I know, this kind of "pipe" function where you accept a variable number of arguments, each of which is a function whose input depends on the output of the previous function, is not possible in current Typescript and not likely to be possible soon. The problem is that it requires an unbounded number of inference passes. [Here's a vaguely similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47393) on the issue tracker discussing this limitation, and [another one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25826).

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you. This is most certainly the answer.

Comment: @TaggedLiteral you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose), there you can find an example of typing `compose` and `pipe`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine So I guess I should have been more careful with my words - as far as I know this isn't possible if you want the function types to be inferred, as in the question's example, but your solution seems to work if the functions' types are declared instead of inferred. Perhaps that is good enough for OP's use-case since the types are still checkable by the compiler. I'll leave it to you to write an answer, if you want to - I don't think I will do a very good job if I try to write an answer based on your article.

Comment: @kaya3 if my solution is ok for OP then it is a duplicated question for sure. But thank you for your position

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Not exactly, because OP wants a "merge" (an intersection, I think) of the preceding parameter types. I am not sure there is a duplicate of that.

Comment: @TaggedLiteral are you looking for something like [that](https://catchts.com/chain-callbacks) ?

Comment: @kaya3 you are right, waiting for OP's response